# How to disable link button after click (no JQuery)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I want to disable link button after user click on it.
But I made something wrong here.

Button is still enabled after click. What am I doing wrong?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="submit" runat="server" 
        CssClass="button" 
        Text="OK" 
        OnClick="Submit_Click" 
        OnClientClick="this.disabled=true">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: If it's doing a postback, I believe the button will be restored to enabled.  You may want to disable it in the codebehind instead of client-side.

Comment: No. In code behind I set enabled=false and after postback it is disabled. But user can fast click on button before submit and make multiple actions and I need to prevent this.

Comment: That makes sense.  Are you getting an error in the console?

Comment: setting it in the code behind would only make a difference after the page reloads. immediately after the click the button will remain enabled

Comment: Also, I would move it to a javascript function, and debug `this` to see what element we're actually dealing with.

Comment: Okay, I just tried your code and it works.  The only thing I can suggest is adding the missing `;` to the end of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Just give `return false;` to your JavaScript. The reason is that your `asp:LinkButton` is getting rendered like this.

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$submit','')" 
   class="button" 
   id="ContentPlaceHolder1_submit" 
   onclick="this.disabled = true;return false;">
OK</a>
```

So, if you do not give return false, these things happens

1. It fires the onclick event <strike>and disables the anchor tag.</strike> (anchor tag does not have a disabled property. `button` and `input type="submit"` has that property.)
2. It moves on to fire the postback and hits the server side click event
3. As there is a postback, the client side JavaScript disabling wont persist (even if it were a button)

By enforcing `return false` you are asking the `asp:LinkButton` not to do anymore processing.

P.S: I have been using [PostBack Ritalin](http://encosia.com/downloads/postback-ritalin/) to prevent multiple clicks on `asp:Button`. IMO, its definitely worth a look in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Use the javascript debugger to check the method is being called. LinkButtons are server generated javascript powered anchor tags & therefore can be tricky.

Answer (score -2):

Try this java script function ,

On your **OnClientClick**

```
    <asp:LinkButton  ID="submit" CssClass="button"  Text="OK" onclick="myButtonId_Click(this);return false;" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

add function ,

```
    protected void myButtonId_Click(target) {
     target.disabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: That hides the button, not disables it & only makes a difference once the page reloads.

Comment: That still works server-side AFTER the postback, not before as OP requested